# How many ways can a sequence of $1$s be partitioned into pairs or singles?

Tags: combinatorics, tetration

> How many distinct ways can a sequence of $n$ $1$s be partitioned into pairs or singles, in which $\{1,1\}=\{2\}$ is considered a pair and $\{1\}$ is considered a single?

For example $\{1,1,1,1\}$ can be partitioned into:

$\{2,2\}$

$\{1,2,1\}$

But

$\{2,1,1\}$
and
$\{1,1,2\}$
are equivalent to $\{2,2\}$

No result containing $\{1,1,1\}$ should be enumerated since this is a triple and has not been partitioned into pairs or singles.

So for $n=4$, the answer is $2$ ways.

I *think* the answer to this question describes the the number of Dyck words which give unique results when exponentiating powers of $2$... as discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028417/).  Or it is at least part of the answer in respect of the fact that it factors out the identity $2^4=4^2$.

Comment: Did you mean to say that $\{ 2,1,1\}$ and $\{1,1,2\}$ are the same as $\{1,2,1\}$? Also, would $\{ 1,1,1,1 \}$ be a third partition for $n = 4$?

Comment: I don't understand your equivalence relation.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume he meant to write what Bram28 suggested...

Comment: but then everyone is equivalent to $\{1,1,1,1\}$

Comment: @Bram28 no, the opposite; $\{ 2,1,1\}\sim\{ 2,2\}\sim \{ 1,1,2\}$ but $\{ 1,2,1\}$ is distinct from them.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I am defining an equivalence relation.  I *think* it is $\{2,1\}\sim\{1,2\}$

Comment: @RobertFrost But then why not $\{1,2,1\} \sim \{1,1,1,1\} \sim \{1,1,2 \}$?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I think the interpretation in your answer is correct.

Comment: So, for $n=3$ does this mean that $\{1,1,1\}$, $\{2,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ are *all* equivalent? Because if so that doesn't seem to be the prevailing interpretation below (I.e. no two consecutive 1s).

Comment: @N.Shales My intent - which is perhaps not clear in the question - is that $\{1,1,1\}$ has not been partitioned into pairs and singles and is therefore not a valid solution.  It's a triple.

Comment: @RobertFrost Okay I misspoke $\{1,1,1\}$ was just to represent the set to be partitioned but if $\{1,2\}$ is equivalent to $\{2,1\}$ then this isn't the same as an ordered sum of 1s and 2s with no consecutive 1s. If it was then $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ would be counted as distinct.

Comment: @N.Shales good point

Comment: @N.Shales then I think the relation is more like $\{2,\{1,1\}\}=\{\{1,1\},\{1,1\}\}$

Comment: @RobertFrost so $\{\{1,1\},1\}$ is different from $\{1,\{1,1\}\}$ then? I'm still confused about the problem statement although I do understand both answers, I just can't quite see that the problem *must* be interpreted this way. Despite this I cannot think of a better interpretation.

Comment: @N.Shales: What Robert wants here is certainly not an equivalence relation for the reason both *mercio* and *Bram28* already mentioned above. But one can define a partial order where for any two sequences $x,y$ we have $x<y$ iff $x$ can be obtained by replacing some pair of adjacent "1"s in $y$ with a "2", some number of times. Then the class of sequences Robert really wants is precisely the class of sequences that each contains only "1"s and/or "2"s and is minimal under this ordering.

Comment: @user21820 what may have thrown N.Shales is my statement that this problem is related to the Dyck Words corresponding to unique values of $2^{2^{\ldots}}$ because in that instance $(2^2)^2=2^{(2^2)}$ which, if this problem were equivalent would indeed suggest $\{1,2\}\sim\{2,1\}$; but that's not the case.  I saw a relation between the two when I wrote the question yesterday. It's to do with the fact every pair $\{2,1\}$ can then be interchanged without changing the value of the tetration.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Whatever it was, I'm just providing a rigorous way to formalize the intuitive notion of pairing; we get a partial order by taking the transitive closure of the ordering given by a reduction by a single pairing operation. So (1,1,2) is **not** equivalent to (2,2) but rather (1,1,2) > (2,2). Similarly (2,1,1) > (2,2). And (1,2,1),(2,2) are incomparable minimal elements.

Comment: @user21820 thank you for formalising the question. This partial order formality, I feel, should be part of the problem statement to avoid any confusion. It certainly avoids the confusion that arises due to the term *equivalent*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to ask is:

"In how many way you can express $n\ge 1$ as *ordered* sum of $1$ and $2$ so that there are no two consecutive ones?"

Solution: Suppose that $n$ is even, i.e., $n=2k$. Then we can place at most $k$ times the number $2$. So, given $i \in \{0,\ldots,k\}$, we miss to place (if possible) $n-2i$ times the number $1$ in the $i+1$ possible positions. Hence the total number is
$$
1+\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k-1}{4}+\cdots=\sum_{j\ge 0}\binom{k+1-j}{2j}.
$$

With a similar argument, if $n$ is odd, i.e., $n=2k+1$, we obtain
$$
(k+1)+\binom{k}{3}+\binom{k-1}{5}+\cdots=\sum_{j\ge 0}{\binom{k+1-j}{2j+1}}.
$$

Comment: This is my interpretation of the question too.

Comment: This is the correct interpretation. Sorry if it was vague. The set $\{1,1,1\}$ would be a triple and therefore not partitioned into pairs and singles and should not be enumerated.

Answer (score 3):

A composition of $n$ can either be a composition of $n-2$ followed by a $2$ or a composition of $n-3$ followed by $2,1$.  This gives the recurrence $f(n)=f(n-2)+f(n-3)$ with $f(1)=1, f(2)=1, f(3)=2.$  We find it, offset, in [OEIS A000931](http://oeis.org/A000931) and it begins $1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 21, 28, 37, 49, 65, 86, 114, 151, 200, 265, 351, 465, 616, 816, 1081, 1432, 1897, 2513, 3329, 4410, 5842, 7739, 10252, 13581, 17991, 23833, 31572, 41824, 55405, 73396, 97229, 128801, 170625$

Comment: Does this agree with Paolo's interpretation of the question?  I've clarified that no sequence of three $1$'s is permitted.  Sorry if it was vague.

Comment: Yes, it agrees. In particular, you can find explicitely the $n$-term of the sequence as a convex combination of the $n$-th powers of the roots of the polynomial $x^3-x-1$.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti we're looking at the Padovan sequence aren't we?

Comment: This is using the same interpretation as @Paolo Leonetti.  In fact, I found it first by essentially his approach, then computed some terms and looked it up in OEIS.  That gave me the recurrence and I recognized how it arose.  Yes, this is the Padovan sequence.  There are many combinatorial interpretations in the OEIS entry.  I didn't see this one.

Comment: @RossMillikan I like both answers... but can only accept 1 :(

Comment: No worries.  I think the two answers complement each other.  I have plenty of points not to be concerned.