# How many distinct ways can a sequence of $n$ 1s be partitioned into triples and singles?

Tags: combinatorics

Following on from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271668):

> How many distinct ways can a sequence of $n$ $1$s be partitioned into triples or singles, in which $\{1,1,1\}=\{3\}$ is considered a triple and $\{1\}$ is considered a single?

For example $\{1,1,1,1,1\}$ can be partitioned into:

$\{3,1,1\}$

$\{1,3,1\}$

$\{1,3,1\}$

But no result containing $\{1,1,1\}$ should be enumerated since this should be counted as a triple.

So for $n=5$, the answer is 3 ways.

I *think* the answer to this question equals the number of Dyck words which give unique results when exponentiating powers of $2$... as asked in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028417), since groups of 3 powers of 2 always give the same result; 16 irrespective of order, but the orders of carrying out individual exponents around them make distinct results.

Number of solutions for small $N$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}n & N\\1&1\\2&1\\3&1\\4&2\\5&3\\6&3\\7&4\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see… using Millikan's approach on the other question, a partition of $n$ is one of the following:

- partition of $n-3$ + `3`
- partition of $n-4$ + `31`
- partition of $n-5$ + `311`

Therefore $f(n)=f(n-3)+f(n-4)+f(n-5)$ with $f(1,2,3,4,5)=1,1,1,2,3$. This is [OEIS A017818](https://oeis.org/A017818).

Comment: $n=1, N=1$ is probably a better value isn't it?

Comment: @RobertFrost Yes. And $n=0,N=1$ because it is the empty sum.

Comment: I think I'm getting a different sequence 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 13

Comment: @RobertFrost That _is_ the OEIS sequence I linked. There's nothing wrong!

Comment: Oh ok sorry, my bad!  We need $n=12$ to discriminate this one: https://oeis.org/A218947 or does your solution do that already?

Comment: @RobertFrost Nevertheless, do you agree that my answer is correct?

Comment: The reasoning looks right but I didn't understand how it was pulled from OEIS

Comment: @RobertFrost You need _enough_ terms. The recurrence formula I wrote is in the OEIS entry for A017818.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now.